# How to run Iojs in Docker?

Tags: node.js, docker, dockerfile, iojs

I have the following Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:14.10

ENV HOMEDIR /usr/share/iojs

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install software-properties-common python-software-properties -qq -y && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -qq -y supervisor npm

RUN cd ${HOMEDIR} && \
    wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/creationix/nvm/v0.26.1/install.sh | bash && \
    . ~/.nvm/nvm.sh && \
    nvm install iojs

RUN supervisorctl restart iojs

EXPOSE 80

CMD ["/usr/bin/supervisord", "-n"]
```

And `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/supervisord.conf`

```
[supervisord]
autostart=true
autorestart=true
nodaemon=true

[program:iojs]
directory=/usr/share/iojs
command=/usr/bin/iojs index.js
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

Note: scripts are in `/usr/share/iojs`

Comment: Err, so what happens or doesn't happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a different approach, not saying that yours doesn't work. Why not start from the iojs image based off of Debian 8 in dockerhub.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM iojs
# ...
```

supervisord conf:

```
[supervisord]
autostart=true
autorestart=true
nodaemon=true

[program:iojs]
directory=/usr/share/iojs
command=/usr/local/bin/iojs index.js
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

Comment: Ha, never thought to look in Docker hub for an iojs repo. Let my give this one a try...